# How to create link pointing to Spring controller action that returns void

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am using spring mvc, hateoas. I have a controller action that looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/images/{userId}/{publicUrl}/{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void image(@PathVariable Integer userId, @PathVariable String publicUrl, @PathVariable String fileName, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try(HellodoxAws aws = haws;){
        .....
        .....
        response.setContentType(image.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
        response.setHeader("ETag",image.getObjectMetadata().getETag());
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control",image.getObjectMetadata().getCacheControl());
        response.setHeader("Last-Modified",image.getObjectMetadata().getLastModified().toString());
        IOUtils.copy(image.getObjectContent(), response.getOutputStream());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        if(e instanceof AmazonS3Exception){
            int statusCode = ((AmazonS3Exception) e).getStatusCode();
            //System.out.println("Status Code : "+statusCode);
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            if(statusCode==HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED.value()){
                response.setHeader("ETag",((AmazonS3Exception) e).getAdditionalDetails().get("ETag"));
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control",((AmazonS3Exception) e).getAdditionalDetails().get("Cache-Control"));
                response.setHeader("Last-Modified",((AmazonS3Exception) e).getAdditionalDetails().get("Last-Modified"));
            }
            response.setStatus(statusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

This action works perfectly well.

Now what I want is to publish url to access each profiles' image. JSON format is some thing like this

```
{
    "profileId" : 342308,
    "userId" : 342308,
    "firstname" : "Henry",
    "lastname" : "Seol",
    "title" : "Mr.",
    "largeImageUrl" : "https://<host>/image/<id>/<publicUrl>/<filename1.jpg>",
    "thumbImageUrl" : "https://<host>/image/<id>/<publicUrl>/<filename2.jpg>"
}
```

I want to add that link in place of the value for "largeImageUrl" and "thumbImageUrl".

If I use linkTo function of hateoas it says controller's corresponding method should not return void.

How to create these kind of dynamic link and add it to the resource?

Comment: You can always use `linkTo(...).slash(...)...` as last resort. I wonder why the method's return type is `void` when you actually return an image. Having `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse` as parameters is a no-go.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to return image in this controller by not using HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse as parameters, or any other solution for this controller?

Comment: One alternative is to return `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>`. The `InputStreamResource` can be created with `new InputStreamResource(image.getObjectContent())`, I assume.

Comment: While in this specific example may perhaps be changed, there are others where void is ok and by design, e.g. action applies side effect and returns no content.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the

```
public static ControllerLinkBuilder linkTo(Class<?> controller, Method method, Object... parameters) {
```

So it should be something like

```
Link link = linkTo(
  ImageController.class,
  ImageController.class
    .getMethod("image", Integer.class, String.class, String.class, HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class),
  1,
  "url",
  "file"
).withRel("image");
```

**Note :** 
There is a shorter method

```
public static ControllerLinkBuilder linkTo(Method method, Object... parameters) {
```

but it has a bug therefore it does not work