# String Hateoas link to a void method

Tags: spring, hateoas, spring-hateoas, hal

I am working with Spring Hateoas for HAL standards in HTTP response. I have a HTTP DELETE method in my controller which returns nothing (void). And in the response for same entity I want to provide a link to delete a resource. I tried to do with following code but it gives error

> Cannot resolve method linkTo(void)

```
    resource.add(linkTo(
            methodOn(DokumenteController.class)
                    .loeschenEinDokument(filenetDokumentZuordnung.getDokumentId()))
                            .withRel("download"));
```

Is there any way I can add a link to a method which returns void?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574431/how-to-create-link-pointing-to-spring-controller-action-that-returns-void, could help, although the single answer hasn't been accepted nor upvoted...

Comment: This is a very nice Github link to look at. The short answer is: it cannot be done directly. The answer provided by 'a better olive' is the best you can do. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/1173

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't return `void`. Return `ResponseEntity<Void>` instead.

Chances are, that you have to set some headers anyway, even if you don't return a message body. Or you want to set a status code.

If your controller has an appropriate request mapping you can also do the following:

```
 resource.add(linkTo(DokumenteController.class)
             .slash(filenetDokumentZuordnung.getDokumentId())
             .withRel("download"));
```

Comment: It might be worth reformatting the response to emphasize that there are two answers here, I found the 2nd to be a better fit for my case.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it's possible to link to a `DELETE` route.

Hateoas is allowing you to discover your REST API, but a REST API means that in order to delete the document available at `/document/42` you should call the same route, but with a `DELETE` method.

Basically, you don't have to make a link to your deletion method, because it is implicit that this is the way to delete your document.

Comment: It makes sense to have separate links for each CRUD operation to give the client information about if a specific operation is allowed or not. If the client receives a href with relation name 'deleteDocument', delete would be allowed. If not, it is not allowed.